# Memset in 2D arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, memset

I have a problem with a static 2D array. I want to reset the elements after the k + 1 th line and I want to use memset.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't reset all the lines after the k + 1 th line:

```
int a[505][505];
..................
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
     for(int j=1;j<=m;j++)
         f >> a[i][j];
memset(a + k + 1 , 0 , sizeof(int) * (m + 1) * (n - k));
```

This code doesn't reset all the lines after the k + 1 th line.

edit: n = how many lines the 2d arrays has m = how many columns the 2d arrays has

edit: I have a bigger problem and I need to reset the k + 1 th line every time I do something in my problem.

Comment: Indexes in c++ are 0 based. so `a[0]` to `a[504]` is valid. If `n` and `m` are `505` (which is my guess) then you will have out of bounds indexes.

Comment: then what I need to modify? I don't understand why that code doesn't reset all the elements after the k + 1 th line

Comment: I don't know. What is `m`? What is `n`? Please share a [MCVE]. This example is not complete enough to answer your question.

Comment: n = how many lines the 2d arrays has
m = how many columns the 2d arrays has

Comment: Then you have undefined behavior due to the problem described in my first comment.

Comment: Please post the [mcve]. "it doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Include the expected and the actual output in the MCVE as well as initialization of those arrays. Currently I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: doesn't work = not clear all the elemnts after the k + 1 th line

Comment: The memset looks like you also have a off by one error in the first and third parameter. `sizeof(int) * (m + 1) * (n - k)` will only work if `m = 504`.

Comment: First of all, if you have an array whose size is known only at run-time, use `std::vector`. Then if you want it to be zero-initialized, then do it at initialization. As in `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(n, std::vector<int>(m));`.

Comment: Make sure n and m are less than 505. Your program will break if either of these are 505 or greater.

Comment: I have a bigger probem and I have to reset it like how I descripted every time I do something. I don't want to use stl things.

Comment: @drescherjm this is not the problem

Comment: Other than the improper indexing, we probably can't help until you can reproduce the bug with a minimal example. [mcve] there is not enough information for us to go on.

Comment: @mch and how can fix that thing for any value of m ?

Comment: If you program in C++, use what you have, including the standard library! It will make your life as a C++ programmer *so* much easier.

Comment: Instead of `memset` you can zero-initialize like this: `int a[505][505]{};`.

Comment: Did you try `memset(a + k + 1 , 0 , sizeof *a * (n - k - 1));`? `memset` writes to a memory block, so you have to delete the whole row, not only the first `m` ints.

Comment: I don't want to initialize the array with 0, I have to reset it every I do something in a bigger problem.

Comment: @mch it doesn't work

Comment: So *reset* it when and if needed? Using my vector above, `a = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(n, std::vector<int>(m));` And perhaps it's time you update your question to tell us your *real* problem that you want to solve? ***Why*** do you need to "reset" it? If you ask for help with a solution to an unknown problem then that's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ask about your *real* problem, and tell us how you have attempted so solve it.

Comment: Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Good questions leads to good answers, bad questions to bad answers (and a lot of speculation and guessing and comments).

Comment: Do you want to delete only the `k + 1`th line or this line and everything behind it? Your first and last line in the question tell something different.

Comment: Oh and if you want to reset a single "line" or "row" using vectors: `a[x] = {};`

Comment: @someprogrammerdude I don't want to reset just a single line

Comment: You can reset a line with `memset(a[k + 1], 0, sizeof *a);`

Answer (score 4):

Indices of arrays start from `0`. So if you have an array of `N` elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, N)`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how you can use the function `memset` with an integer array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    const size_t M = 10;
    int a[N][M];

    size_t k = 2;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < k; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ ) a[i][j] = M * i + j;
    }

    std::memset( a[k], 0, ( N - k ) * M * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &value : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << value << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }        
}
```

Its output is

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

If you want to reset to zeroes just one line (for example k-th line) then the call of memset will look like

```
std::memset( a[k], 0, M * sizeof( int ) );
```

A more general approach is to use the standard algorithm `std::fill`. For example

```
std::fill( std::begin( a[k] ), std::end( a[k] ), 0 );
```

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    const size_t M = 10;
    int a[N][M];

    size_t k = 2;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ ) a[i][j] = M * i + j;
    }

    std::fill( std::begin( a[k] ), std::end( a[k] ), 0 );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &value : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << value << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }        

}
```

The program at first sequentially fills all elements of the array and then resets the row k-th to zeroes.

Of course it would be simpler initially to declare the array initializing it with zeroes without calling the function `memset` (the compiler will do it itself).

```
int a[N][M] = {};
```

Comment: in my case resets just k th line

Comment: @Sochuu What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Sochuu It is not important. I shpwed a general approach.

Comment: @Quimby I am using c++14. I don't want to reset the k th line. I want to reset all the elements after the k + 1 th line.

Comment: @Sochuu but the code posted in this answer does just that, it doesn't work for you?C++14 is not a compiler, I meant like clang,gcc,visual studio...

Comment: I didn't copied what he did, I updated in my program. I didn't try to add 1 to k.

Comment: @Quimby with fill, works, but is too slow. I want with memset

Comment: @Sochuu This is memset `std::memset( a[k], 0, ( N - k ) * M * sizeof( int ) );` as the OP posted. Highly doubt the fill will be slower when optimizations are enabled.

Comment: @Sochuu *fill, works, but is too slow. I want with memset* – Then provide code of \*how\* you measured \*what\* or that never happened. Also, when you think you *need* memset because it is "faster", what is wrong with the example at the bottom of my answer?

Comment: `std::fill` is compiled into a call to `memset` on pretty much every compiler and standard library implementation, so your claim that `std::fill` is too slow so you want to use `memset` instead defies logic, @Sochuu. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. Update your question with a test case providing these performance claims, and someone will be happy to investigate.

Answer (score 4):

We don't do C here ... and please use identifiers with more letters than M and N.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, std::size_t ROWS, std::size_t COLS>
void print_arr(T (&arr)[COLS][ROWS])
{
    for (size_t row{}; row < ROWS; ++row) {
        std::copy(&arr[row][0], &arr[row][0] + COLS,
                  std::ostream_iterator<T>{ std::cout, "\t" });
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');
}

template<typename T, std::size_t ROWS, std::size_t COLS>
void kill_all_from_line_till_last(T (&arr)[COLS][ROWS], std::size_t kill_from)
{
    std::fill(&arr[kill_from][0], &arr[kill_from][0] + (ROWS - kill_from) * COLS, T{});
}

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t rows    { 10 };
    constexpr size_t columns { 10 };

    int arr[rows][columns];
    std::iota(&arr[0][0], &arr[0][0] + columns * rows, 1);
    print_arr(arr);

    kill_all_from_line_till_last(arr, 7);

    print_arr(arr);
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20
21      22      23      24      25      26      27      28      29      30
31      32      33      34      35      36      37      38      39      40
41      42      43      44      45      46      47      48      49      50
51      52      53      54      55      56      57      58      59      60
61      62      63      64      65      66      67      68      69      70
71      72      73      74      75      76      77      78      79      80
81      82      83      84      85      86      87      88      89      90
91      92      93      94      95      96      97      98      99      100

1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20
21      22      23      24      25      26      27      28      29      30
31      32      33      34      35      36      37      38      39      40
41      42      43      44      45      46      47      48      49      50
51      52      53      54      55      56      57      58      59      60
61      62      63      64      65      66      67      68      69      70
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

---

### The Pseudo-C Version:

... using `std::memset()` looks almost the same:

```c
#include <cstring>

template<typename T, std::size_t ROWS, std::size_t COLS>
void kill_all_from_line_till_last(T (&arr)[COLS][ROWS], std::size_t kill_from)
{
    std::memset(&arr[kill_from][0], 0, (ROWS - kill_from) * COLS * sizeof(T));
}
```

but you only can use that for PODs.

---

### Speed:

Since you mentioned that you found that `std::fill()` is too slow for your needs compared to `std::memset()`

@Sochuu:

> with fill, works, but is too slow. I want with memset

```cpp
constexpr size_t rows    { 10 };
constexpr size_t columns { 10 };
{
    int arr[rows][columns];
    std::iota(&arr[0][0], &arr[0][0] + columns * rows, 1);
    print_arr(arr);
    kill_all_from_line_till_last_fill(arr, 7);
    print_arr(arr);
}
{
    int arr[rows][columns];
    std::iota(&arr[0][0], &arr[0][0] + columns * rows, 1);
    print_arr(arr);
    kill_all_from_line_till_last_memset(arr, 7);
    print_arr(arr);
}
```

---

#### gcc

Assembly from gcc 9.1 (`--std=c++14 -O3 -Wall`):

```
    ; ...

    call    void print_arr<int, 10ul, 10ul>(int (&) [10ul][10ul])
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     ecx, 15
    mov     rdi, rbx
    rep stosq
    mov     rdi, rsp
    call    void print_arr<int, 10ul, 10ul>(int (&) [10ul][10ul])

    ; ...

    call    void print_arr<int, 10ul, 10ul>(int (&) [10ul][10ul])
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     rdi, rbx
    mov     ecx, 15
    rep stosq
    mov     rdi, rsp
    call    void print_arr<int, 10ul, 10ul>(int (&) [10ul][10ul])

    ; ...
```

As you see for both versions exactly the same code is generated between the calls to `print_arr()`. Compilers aren't (that) stupid.

Full Code: [godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8ACfK5)

---

#### clang

Same for clang 8.3.0 (`--std=c++14 -Ofast3 -Wall`), exactly the same code vor both, `std::fill()` and `std::memset()`:

```
    ; ...

    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    void print_arr<int, 10ul, 10ul>(int (&) [10ul][10ul])
    xorps   xmm0, xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 376], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 360], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 344], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 328], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 312], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 296], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 280], xmm0
    mov     qword ptr [rsp + 392], 0
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    void print_arr<int, 10ul, 10ul>(int (&) [10ul][10ul])

    ; ...

    call    void print_arr<int, 10ul, 10ul>(int (&) [10ul][10ul])
    xorps   xmm0, xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 376], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 360], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 344], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 328], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 312], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 296], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 280], xmm0
    mov     qword ptr [rsp + 392], 0
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    void print_arr<int, 10ul, 10ul>(int (&) [10ul][10ul])
    
    ; ...
```

Full Code: [godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/3TwX7b)

---

### msvc

Microsoft cl 19.20 (`/O2`):

```
    ; ...

    call    void print_arr<int,10,10>(int (&)[10][10])
    xorps   xmm0, xmm0
    lea     rcx, QWORD PTR arr$2[rsp]
    xor     eax, eax
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$2[rsp+280], xmm0
    mov     QWORD PTR arr$2[rsp+392], rax
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$2[rsp+296], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$2[rsp+312], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$2[rsp+328], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$2[rsp+344], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$2[rsp+360], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$2[rsp+376], xmm0
    call    void print_arr<int,10,10>(int (&)[10][10])     ; 

    ; ...

    call    void print_arr<int,10,10>(int (&)[10][10])
    xorps   xmm0, xmm0
    lea     rcx, QWORD PTR arr$1[rsp]
    xor     eax, eax
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$1[rsp+280], xmm0
    mov     QWORD PTR arr$1[rsp+392], rax
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$1[rsp+296], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$1[rsp+312], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$1[rsp+328], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$1[rsp+344], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$1[rsp+360], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR arr$1[rsp+376], xmm0
    call    void print_arr<int,10,10>(int (&)[10][10])

    ; ...
```

Full Code: [godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/gN5QzH)

I think that experiment can end at this point.